# How to trigger workflow from button in O365

Tags: workflow, office-365

I created a script editor webpart. I added a button which start a js function in the onClick event. I would like to start a workflow which is implemented on some list. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to trigger workflow on particular list item?

Comment: Do you want to add a custom button that user will click when he wants to trigger workflow versus item added or updated?

Comment: pls mark my answer if it has solved your problems

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at what the URL is from the Item > Workflows > Start Workflow option on the specific one you want to run, that's the only way I can think of to start it but it would be a nightmare to make sure the workflow GUID and item ID are correct in the URL, so I would maybe try to find some other way to do this.

For the sake of a few clicks, it seems like a lot of effort for not very much gain.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely possible, You can use SPServices.Js to achieve this. Actually you need to create a specific URL that will redirect you to WF Initiation page. It will have structure Like:

```
*../sites/your_sitename/layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List="+your_List_guid+"&ID="+<your_ItemID>+"&TemplateID={"+WFguid+"}&Source=https://....";*
```

Here Last parameter &Source= is optional. On click of a button, I will do manipulation and redirect you to Workflow initiation page

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
var path;
var ItemID;
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("xxxxxxxx");
var item;

//to get list GUID -- start
var ListID = "";
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetList",
listName: "xxxxxxxx",
async: false,
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
ListID = $(xData.responseXML).find("List").attr("ID");
}
});
//to get list GUID -- end

//to get Template ID of workflow -- start
var itemurl;
var f = "<ViewFields>"+
                '<FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl"/>'+
            "</ViewFields>";
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: "xxxxxxxx",
CAMLViewFields: f,
ID: ItemID,
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
  $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
      itemurl = $(this).attr("ows_EncodedAbsUrl")
    });
  }
});
var guid;
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetTemplatesForItem",
  item: itemurl,
  async: false,
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    var currentItemURL = this.item;
    $(xData.responseXML).find("WorkflowTemplates > WorkflowTemplate").each(function (i, e) {
      if ($(this).attr("Name") == "your WF display name") {
        guid = $(this).find("WorkflowTemplateIdSet").attr("TemplateId");
       }
    });
  }
});
//to get Template ID of workflow -- end


path="<siteUrl>/sites/xxxx/_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List="+ListID+"&ID="+ItemID+"&TemplateID={"+guid+"}&Source=<URL where you want to redirect post WF action>";

window.open(path,'_self');
});
```

Comment: This is what I was getting at, I just wasn't sure of how you'd pull down the neccessary values!

Comment: I think my code is helpful for you to get all required details? please mark this as answer if it solved your issue. Do let me know in case of query! :)