# Override "Onclick" event of Custom action button of Ribbon to an HTML button on a sitepage

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-action

I have created a workflow that starts manually on a custom action button.
But now how do I get this implemented into an HTML button that is placed on a Sitepage.

Inshort, need to override the onclick event of custom action button from ribbon to an HTML button on a sitepage.

Is it possible?

Comment: **Absolutely Possible**, Please refer my [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218198/how-to-trigger-workflow-from-button-in-o365/218204#218204) on another thread