# SharePoint online, workflow 2010 approval workflow

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, approval, online

Is there a way to run a SharePoint approval workflow 2010 association workflow from javascript? - it's not a subscription 
There is no option of using SP 2013 workflow.

I've checked out and tried to modify it but it doesn't work

- [Start SharePoint Workflows with JavaScript Client Object Model](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/08/start-sharepoint-2013-workflows-with.html)
- [Trigger SP2010 Workflows using JSOM](https://chuvash.eu/2016/05/19/trigger-sp2010-workflows-using-jsom/)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes,** You can run any SharePoint workflow by properly redirecting to WF initiation page in a specific URL format. below is the sequence one should have to run a workflow:

```
../sites/your_sitename/layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List="+your_List_guid+"&ID="+<your_ItemID>+"&TemplateID={"+WFguid+"}
```

Please refer to my another [Answer Thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218198/how-to-trigger-workflow-from-button-in-o365/218204#218204) where I have explained how to use javascript code to initiate the Workflow